# Using Axios in VueJS - this undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Using typescript and vuejs + axios, i have the following .catch function on a post request - I'm attempting to trap some network errors and report status to the end user:

```
      .catch(function(error) {
          console.error(error.response);
          if ( error.message === "Network Error" ) {
              this.alert.show = 1;
              this.alert.message = error.message + ': Please try again later';
          }
      });
```

this.alert.show throws "this" undefined in the debugger.  Is this a problem with javascript/typescript and exception handlers in general, or is this a bug in Axios or a design decision I can't find documentation for?

And is there a way for me to communicate this back to my component absent a "this" reference?

Full block:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        email: '',
        password: '',
      },
      alert: {
          show: 0,
          message: '',
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      if (this.form.password.length > 0) {
          // TODO: Hideous workaround for .catch().
          let that = this;
          this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', {
              email: this.form.email,
              password: this.form.password,
          })
          .then((response) => {
              const is_admin = response.data.user.is_admin;
              localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data.user));
              localStorage.setItem('jwt', response.data.token);

              if (localStorage.getItem('jwt') != null) {
                  this.$emit('loggedIn');
                  if (this.$route.params.nextUrl != null) {
                      this.$router.push(this.$route.params.nextUrl);
                  } else {
                      if (is_admin === 1) {
                          this.$router.push('admin');
                      } else {
                          this.$router.push('dashboard');
                      }
                  }
              }

          })
          .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
                if ( error.message === 'Network Error' ) {
                    this.alert.show = 10;
                    this.alert.message = error.message + ': Please try again later';
                }
          });
      }
    },
    onReset(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      /* Reset our form values */
      this.form.email = '';
      this.form.password = '';
      /* Trick to reset/clear native browser form validation state */
      this.show = false;
      this.$nextTick(() => { this.show = true; });
    },
  },
};
```

Vue template (Login.vue):

```
<template>
<div>
<b-container class="loginPage">
  <b-row>
    <b-col sm="4"/>
    <b-col sm="4">
      <b-form @submit="onSubmit" @reset="onReset">
         <h2>Login</h2>
         <p>Please enter your email and password</p>
         <b-form-input id="exampleInput1"
                      type="email"
                      v-model="form.email"
                      required
                      placeholder="Enter email">
         </b-form-input>
         <b-form-input id="exampleInput2"
                      type="password"
                      v-model="form.password"
                      required
                      placeholder="Enter password">
         </b-form-input>
      </b-form-group>

        <div class="forgot">
        <a href="reset.html">Forgot password?</a>
        </div>

      <b-button class="btn-primary" type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
      <b-button class="btn-reset"   type="reset" variant="danger">Reset</b-button>

      <b-alert :show="alert.show" variant="danger">
         {{alert.message}}
      </b-alert>
    </b-form>

    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="4"/>
  </b-row>
</b-container >


    </div>
</template>
```

Also using https://bootstrap-vue.js.org.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're creating a new local function scope. Use fat arrow instead.

```
.catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.response);
      if ( error.message === "Network Error" ) {
          this.alert.show = 1;
          this.alert.message = error.message + ': Please try again later';
      }
  });
```

Comment: Interesting.  error.response becomes undefined, but the debugger still shows this is undefined, and yet my login alert box ends up showing up anyway.  A lot of basic javascript is still new to me, even using it for years.

Comment: Can you show more of this block? How is the greater function being called?  Scope could be lost in a few ways.

Comment: your solution is the best, i think he lost the context somewhere else

Comment: I believe you are correct, this is best solution.  It seems to work in the browser (chromium) but the debugger still shows it's undefined.  Adding whole block.  Seems to only work once.

Comment: How are you using this within the context of Vue?

Comment: Updated with vue template.

Answer (score 8):

You could also assign `this` to a global variable and access it inside callback :

```
    let that =this;
    ...
    .catch((error) => {
  console.error(error.response);
  if ( error.message === "Network Error" ) {
      that.alert.show = 1;
      that.alert.message = error.message + ': Please try again later';
  }
  });
```

Comment: Are there any side effects to storing `this` in a variable? Does it get garbage collected normally?

Comment: when  your app/component is destroyed the variable (reference) will be also destroyed, it's not a copy it's just a reference, https://blog.penjee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/pass-by-reference-vs-pass-by-value-animation.gif