# How pass data from component to external js file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, dropzone.js

I want to use my component's data within my external JavaScript file, containing my Dropzone configuration. I tried unsuccessfully to use `Function.prototype.bind`:

```js
export const dropzoneConfig = {
    url: api.http.baseUrl + '/files',
    thumbnailWidth: 150,
    maxFilesize: 5,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    sending: function (file, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append('type', 'photo');
    },
    success: function (file, xhr) {
        file.id = xhr.data.id;
        if (this.entry.files === undefined) {
            this.entry.files = [];
        }
        this.entry.files.push(xhr.data);
        this.saveNote();
    }.bind(this),
    headers: api.http.authHeaders().headers
};
```

In the code above, `this.entry` and `this.saveNote` are unavailable because they're from my Vue component. How do I make them accessible to the external file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Axios in VueJS - this undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657696/using-axios-in-vuejs-this-undefined)

Comment: Don't use Vue things in external scripts, do the opposite, wrap it with a component.

Comment: Ok, what if I want to wrap it as a config to several components? How to do this without repeating the same config for two components

Comment: It's unknown what happens with `entry`, so this depends a lot on your case. There are several recipes to share data with nested components - via $root or other global object, $root events, Vuex, provide/inject, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more general solution would be for the component to pass in a `success`-event handler that has access to the component's data and methods, as shown below. This solution decouples the configuration from the component's internals.

*dropzoneConfig.js:*

```js
export const dropzoneConfig = ({ onSuccess }) => ({
  //...
  success(file, xhr) {
    //...
    onSuccess(xhr.data)
  }
})
```

*App.vue:*

```html
<script>
import Dropzone from 'dropzone'
import { dropzoneConfig } from './dropzoneConfig'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      entry: {
        files: []
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    Dropzone.options.myComponent = dropzoneConfig({
      onSuccess: fileData => this.onDropzoneSuccess(fileData)
    })
  },
  methods: {
    saveNote() {
      //...
    },
    onDropzoneSuccess(fileData) {
      this.entry.files.push(fileData)
      this.saveNote()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```