# How i can set/change variable in catch error axios?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

If i try set variable in vue2 when axios error i get this: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'snackbar')

```
            axios.post('/testaxios', {
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
                this.snackbar = true;
            });
```

```
data() {
        return {
            snackbar: false,
        }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Axios in VueJS - this undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657696/using-axios-in-vuejs-this-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to bind the catch function to the `this` context:

```
catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
  this.snackbar = true;
}).bind(this);
```

Or simply use an arrow function (which does the binding automatically):

```
catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  this.snackbar = true;
});
```